# Android EditText change other EditText value

Tags: java, android

When I edit one text field, I want another text field to change.

```
  editTextCount.addTextChangedListener( new TextWatcher( ) {

    @Override
    public void afterTextChanged( Editable arg0 ) {

      if ( arg0.length( ) == 0 ) {
        return;
      }

      editTextAmount.setText( value
          * Integer.parseInt( arg0.toString( ) )+""  );

    }

    @Override
    public void beforeTextChanged( CharSequence arg0, int arg1, int arg2,
        int arg3 ) {
      // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void onTextChanged( CharSequence arg0, int arg1, int arg2,
        int arg3 ) {
      // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

  } );
```

When I edit editTextCount, editTextAmount should change, but nothing happens.

Edit - Also, I forgot to mention this is in a custom ArrayAdapter. Could this be the problem?

Edit2 - I'm an idiot. I was declaring  `EditText editTextAmount` as a class level variable when I should have been declaring it  `final EditText editTextAmount` inside the getView() method. Thanks for all the help everyone. Your answers will help me with errors in the future.

Comment: Are you getting any exception or error messages? Have you verified that `value
          * Integer.parseInt( arg0.toString( )` is the value you expect?

Comment: Yep, I get the right value if i call Sytem.out.print on value
          * Integer.parseInt( arg0.toString( ) ) and on editTextAmount.getText()

Answer (score 2):

I think you need to implement your code in the `onTextChanged()` instead of `afterTextChanged()`. From the [docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/TextWatcher.html#onTextChanged%28java.lang.CharSequence,%20int,%20int,%20int%29):

> This method is called to notify you that, within s, the count
>   characters beginning at start have just replaced old text that had
>   length before.

---

On a side note, you should check for the input of [parseInt](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#parseInt%28java.lang.String%29) before passing the value. It throws an exception in case of invalid number

Answer (score 2):

I am assuming that what you are trying to do is type a number into `editTextCount` and that number will by multiplied by `value` and write the final calculation to `editTextAmount`. If this is the case, why not use,

```
editTextAmount.setText(value * Integer.parseInt(editTextCount.getText()));
```

It's really easy to use an `Editable` object to create an inifinite recursion situation where you are calling `afterTextChanged` infinitely, `afterTextChanged` gets called if what it is listening on, or if its `Editable` object gets changed. Thus if you change the `Editable` object in `afterTextChanged` it will call its self recursively.

It may be worth it to also try printing these values to identify any issues:

```
System.out.println("Value: " + value);
System.out.println("Count: " + Integer.parseInt(editTextCount.getText()));
System.out.println("Amount: " + (value * Integer.parseInt(editTextCount.getText())));
```

Comment: Here's what I get when I print all the values Value: 0.01

editTextCount: 50.0
0
Amount: 0.5

editTextAmount: 0.5. It says the value of editTextAmount changed but it just doesn't appear on the screen

Comment: Are these `EditText` objects defined in XML? If they are, do you have the java `View` for `editTextAmount` properly connected to the XML object? Since you can get the value from `editTextCout`, I'm going to assume that if defined in XML, it's properly connected.

Answer (score 1):

afterTextChanged() should be fine. Are you sure, that some of the values are not initialized properly (e.g. value = 0)?

Comment: Value is initialized properly. Even when I call System.out.println( editTextAmount.getText( ) );, it prints out the right value. It just doesn't change on the screen.

Comment: You could try to get the content from the EditText directly instead of using the Editable and check, if it sets the value properly.